# Why this ORA-06502 error message?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Why does

```
set serveroutput on;
select owa_util.get_cgi_env('REMOTE_ADDR') from dual;
```

generate a `ORA-06502 PL/SQL: numeric or value error`?

I'm running this from TOAD session.

Comment: This works perfectly fine on my end (Oracle 12c and SQL Developer). Have you tried running it somewhere else than in Toad and if the error also occurs there, what's the Oracle DB version you're running on?

Comment: Fails for me too in 11.2.0.3, from SQL Developer and SQL*Plus. But why are you calling an OWA function outside `mod_plsql`? I imagine something isn't initialised when it's called like this. Where would the CGI environment be set up? (Haven't used it so not really sure). Are you particularly needing to call that function because you're testing something OWA-related? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: My goal is to capture the ip address of someone accessing web page which I've written using an Oracle package containing htp/htf code. I found this code from http://c2anton.blogspot.com/2007/02/oracle-portal-client-ip-address.html. I ran the select from dual script in TOAD to conduct a test againt my own ip.

Comment: But from Toad you aren't in the same context as the web-called package, surely, so can it be a meaningful test? Even if it worked. [This might be useful](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1025733?tstart=0) but not really sure.

Comment: I'm not yet seeing the bigger picture, thanks for questions. If this query returns ip address of remote client, and I'm the remote client in this case, wouldn't this test confirm my ip address in both contexts in (web-package) and in toad?

Comment: It returns the IP address of the remote client based on the CGI environment, which is created by `mod_plsql` and Apache, as I understand things. The equivalent for other clients is something like `select sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') from dual`. The two scenarios aren't really comparable, I think (but may be wrong!).

Comment: I understand now. The link is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you Need to initialize before before using the owa routines.

try this code:

```
declare
nm owa.vc_arr;
vl owa.vc_arr;
test_var VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
owa.init_cgi_env( nm.count, nm, vl );
select owa_util.get_cgi_env('REMOTE_ADDR') INTO test_var from dual; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Output-->'||test_var);
end;
```